# Change state of call in iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is it possible we can change state of call from `CTCallStateIncoming` to `CTCallStateConnected`  with in an iOS4 app using `CTelephony` framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I believe these are getters, not setters. Which makes sense because an app shouldn't be interfering with phone functions. Your app is secondary to any incoming call, which is why it's put in a dormant state when calls come in.